# HTML emails in Drupal 8.4

Tags: 8, emails

Some users (not admins) on our system are not having their password reset links sent by `_user_mail_notify('password_reset', $account, $langcode)` work properly. A suspicion is that their e-mail clients are not parsing the entire link as one URL.

In /admin/config/people/accounts, I'm trying to use `[user:one-time-login-url]` as a href attribute, like `<a href="[user:one-time-login-url]">click</a>`.

Using default PHP mailer, this doesn't really change anything, it just makes the link show up as `click [1]` and spits out the URL text at the bottom of the email.

I've had swiftmailer installed for a while, and I use it specifically for some module emails that require attachments. However I avoid using HTML emails as the HTML never parses properly no matter what settings I use. For example, the `<a href=...` code above comes out as `&lt;a href=&quot;https://...` when the e-mail is sent, even if I set Swiftmailer to use HTML and uncheck "Respect provided e-mail format."

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to fix?

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/project/swiftmailer/issues/2831959

Comment: Thanks for the link @Berdir, I installed the latest dev build but the issue still persists.